# Java HashMap add key +1 to every new Value?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, integer, key-value

I´m writing a programm in Java. This programm should handle with a lot of diffrent values. I decided to use a HashMap, as you can see here :

```
public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> users = new HashMap<>();
```

So, as you see I´ve got a map with 2 keys. The first key decides about my "second HashMap". I hope you understood that, because now here is my problem.

```
public class test {

public static Map<Plot, Map<Integer, Player>> users = new HashMap<>();
public void test(String first, String second) {

if(users.get(first).isEmpty() {
users.computeIfAbsent(first, (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(0, null);
}

if(!users.get(first).containsValue(second)) {
users.computeIfAbsent(first, (a)->new HashMap<>()).put(/*my problem*/, second);
    }
  }
}
```

So, in the last if-statement is a comment. I don´t know what i should write in there ? This method is called by another class, but that doesnt matter. My goal is, that to every String (first Key) will be saved a certain Integer (second key) with a certain value(second String in my method). 
Of course I want every String to start with 0 and have its own chronologically order. But remember, you can´t use at the start of the class a normal Integer-var, because if you should use it for every key it wouldn´t solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the 'inner map' (the one with type `Map<Integer, String>`) will at all times adhere to the following rule:

The map's keys will always cover a closed range from 0 to its size. For example, an inner map of size 8 will have as keys: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].

Assuming I parsed your question correctly, you.... **made a list**. A list *IS* semantically speaking exactly that: A thing that 'maps' a closed range of integers starting from 0 to values. To read from this 'map' the value associated with 'key' 5, you just call `list.get(5)`. To 'add' an item at the end, you just call `list.add(x)` instead of `map.put(???, x)`.

Thus, the answer is as trivial as: Replace `Map<Integer, String>` with `List<String>`, replace the `(a)->new HashMap<>()` with `a->new ArrayList<>()`, and replace `.put(/*my problem*/,` with `.add(`.

If you must do this with maps, you cannot do it with hashmaps, unless you try to use map.size() as a fragile standin, which I strongly advise you don't do (as that would imply your map only works in cases where list would be better, thus proving that the map solution is inferior) – hashmaps do not have an order and thus no idea of 'what is the last / highest key'. You can use a TreeMap instead, which DOES have such concepts. You can ask it about the highest key, and then use 1 higher than that.

But I'm pretty sure you just want a list here.